# Struct equality with arrays

Tags: struct, julia, equals, mutable

If I have arrays in a struct as below, I can't compare the equality of the struct because the arrays are mutable? Is there a way to get the equality to pass down to the array so that I get `true` for `a([1,2,3]) == a([1,2,3])`? Or is the only way to do this to extend `Base.==`?

```
julia> struct a
       v
       end

julia> a([1,2,3]) == a([1,2,3])
false

julia> a(1) == a(1)
true

julia> [1,2,3] == [1,2,3] # want the equality to work like this for the struct
true

julia> [1,2,3] === [1,2,3]
false
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer by @miguel raz does not work at all!

This happens since `isequal` is actually calling `==` rather than `==` calling `isequal`. In the `isequal` doc you can find explicitely that:

> The default implementation of `isequal` calls `==`, so a type that does not involve
>   floating-point values generally only needs to define `==`

Hence the correct code is:

```
struct A
  v
end
import Base.==
==(x::A,y::A) = x.v==y.v
```

However, a more elegant approach would be to write a generic code that does not rely on having the field `v`. Since we do not want to overload the default `==` operator we can define an `abstract` type that will tell Julia to use our implementation:

```
abstract type Comparable end

import Base.==

function ==(a::T, b::T) where T <: Comparable
    f = fieldnames(T)
    getfield.(Ref(a),f) == getfield.(Ref(b),f)
end
```

Now you can define your own structures that will correctly compare:

```
struct B <: Comparable
    x
    y
end
```

Testing:

```
julia> b1 = B([1,2],[B(7,[1])]);

julia> b2 = B([1,2],[B(7,[1])])

julia> b1 == b2
true
```

Comment: This is nice, although it looks like you are using Julia's inheritance like a typeclass. What happens if the original struct already has a base class?

Comment: Unfortunately Julia does not have multiple inheritance so you will need to define something like `function ==(a::T, b::T) where T <: Union{Comparable,SomeOtherType}`

Answer (score 3):

As @Przemyslaw answered, an overload of `==` is needed.
For situations where an abstract class implementation doesn't work, the overload can be done as a one-liner (avoiding the `import` statement):

```
Base.:(==)(a::A, b::A) = Base.:(==)(a.v, a.v)
```

It's good to also override `isequal` (for structs that don't need special NaN and missing value semantics) and `hash` (for structs that can be used as keys):

```
Base.isequal(a::A, b::A) = Base.isequal(a.v, b.v)
Base.hash(a::A, h::UInt) = Base.hash(a.v, h)
```